# How do I get Multiple raw Http Request Input Stream using IRequiresRequestStream?

Tags: stream, servicestack

I am trying upload multiple file using service stack. Below code is working fine for one file upload. I want to upload multiple file. Please let me know what change should be required so that below codes work for multiple files upload also.

```
 public class Hello : IRequiresRequestStream
    {
        Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
    }
```

At client side I am using 'multipart/form-data' for file upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation on [Uploading Files](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#uploading-files), `IRequiresRequestStream` is only for accessing the Request Body as a Stream of Bytes, to process multiple files uploaded with `multipart/form-data` use the `base.Request.Files` property instead, e.g:

#### Uploading Files

You can access uploaded files independently of the Request DTO using `Request.Files`. e.g:

```
public object Post(MyFileUpload request)
{
    if (this.Request.Files.Length > 0)
    {
        var uploadedFile = base.Request.Files[0];
        uploadedFile.SaveTo(MyUploadsDirPath.CombineWith(file.FileName));
    }
    return HttpResult.Redirect("/");
}
```

ServiceStack's [imgur.servicestack.net](http://imgur.servicestack.net) example shows how to access the [byte stream of multiple uploaded files](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Imgur/blob/master/src/Imgur/Global.asax.cs#L62), e.g:

```
public object Post(Upload request)
{
    foreach (var uploadedFile in base.Request.Files
       .Where(uploadedFile => uploadedFile.ContentLength > 0))
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            uploadedFile.WriteTo(ms);
            WriteImage(ms);
        }
    }
    return HttpResult.Redirect("/");
}
```

Comment: I am  not able to access object  this.Request.Files. it is showing error like "The Namespace or module 'Request' is not define ".

Comment: @chirag base.Request is a normal property on the 'Service' base class, it will be there if your service inherits from Service.

Comment: In servicestack we did all communication using RequestDTO. But here we directly access file using base.Request.Files . Suppose I access file using base.Request.Files then Is there any change of violation of message base design pattern? Beacause we are not using RequestDTO class object of file reading.

Comment: @mythz- Is there any ways that we can access file using requestDTO object.? Means using RequestStream property of DTO class.

Comment: @chirag no files are read directly from the underlying ASP.NET request object

Comment: @mythz- base.Request object is behave similar as ASP.NET request object. am I right?  we are reading file without using RequestDTO class. If we are reading file using RequestDTO class then we get file using RequestStream(Type of Stream).

Comment: @chirag base.Request is a thin wrapper over ASP.NET's Request, but you can't read `multipart/form-data` Request directly as a stream of bytes as mentioned in the first paragraph of this answer.