# Property of RequestDTO is giving wrong value in servicestack

Tags: service, f#, servicestack

```
module FileUploadService = 

  type FileDetails() =
        member val fileName= string with get,set
        interface IRequiresRequestStream with
           member val RequestStream = null with get,set



  type FileService() = 
          inherit Service()
          interface IService
             member this.Post(request : FileDetails ) = 
               //My Logic
               //can not able to read "request.fileName" property value.
```

I am trying to create service using servicestack. RequestDTO has two property (`fileName and RequestStream`).

I am tring to read value of `request.fileName` property and it is showing value `ctor@25`. I don't understand why it is showing `ctor@25` value every time.

**EDIT**- Below code is written at Client side.

```
    function uploadBlobOrFile(fileData) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', "http://172.27.15.26:8000/ById/FileUploadService", true);

        xhr.withCredentials=true;
        xhr.onload = function (e) {
            progressBar.value = 0;
            progressBar.textContent = progressBar.value;
        };
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                console.log("success");
            }
        };
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("fileName", "FileName.txt"); 
        data.append("RequestStream", file);

        xhr.send(data);
    }
```

Comment: This excludes the most important part of this question, the client code or raw HTTP that made the request.

Comment: please check my updated question.

Comment: It looks like you're sending a `multipart/form-data` request not a raw stream of bytes so don't use `IRequiresRequestStream`, use `base.Request.Files` instead. Also `RequestStream` is not a normal property, it represents the entire HTTP Request body as a stream of bytes, i.e. not a single FormData property that your javascript assumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you decorate your Request DTO with `IRequiresRequestStream` you're telling ServiceStack not to read the Request Body as you're [taking over deserializing the Request Stream](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#reading-directly-from-the-request-stream) yourself. However it will still try to populate the Request DTO with the rest of the Request parameters that were submitted with the Request.

Without seeing the actual HTTP Request I can't tell if `fileName` is also included as part of the HTTP Request but if this is a multipart/formdata request the `fileName` is [included in the HTTP Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/913749/85785).

But if it is a `multipart/formdata` Request **DO NOT** [use IRequiresRequestStream to read the request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32014188/85785). IRequiresRequestStream only makes sense if a raw stream of bytes was posted to the URL, it's not for processing `multipart/formdata` which should use `base.Request.Files` which is specifically for processing `multipart/formdata` requests and includes access to additional metadata posted with the File Upload.